# Sharing my MySQL 8.0 database

Tags: java, mysql

I am using MySQL Server 8.0 . I have a database named **tcs**. Now I wanted to share this database with my mentor. I don't want remote database feature, I only want that all the tables that I have made are available in his system so that he can use my application as for running my application those tables must be present in the system.

Comment: So take a database dump and give it to him.

Comment: he is not gonna make the database by himself he has asked me to send my database to him

Comment: So take a database dump and send it to him.

Comment: That's something for you to research about. Good luck!

Comment: Not really. You have access to Google and I've told you what to research. Nothing rude about that. In fact it's very helpful, because as a student you really need to know how to research things, instead of asking other people to hand you out full solutions.

Comment: @Kayaman yaa actually i misread your comment